# JVM Scheme Abstract Syntax Tree access

Tags: java, scheme, kawa

There are a number of Scheme implementations running on the JVM (e.g. JScheme, Kawa).

Do any of them support both of:
a) Two-way interoperability with Java. 
b) Access to the AST for a Scheme expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kawa has two-way interoperability.

From  [Kawa Features](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Features.html):

> Full convenient and efficient access to the huge set of Java libraries
>   means you can access objects, methods, fields, and classes without
>   run-time overhead.

From ["Evaluating Scheme expressions from Java"](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Evaluating-Scheme-expressions-from-Java.html)

> The following methods are recommended if you need to evaluate a Scheme
>   expression from a Java method.

How the Scheme types are represented in Java are described here:

["Scheme types in Java"](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Scheme-types-in-Java.html)

For more information try sending a mail to the Kawa mailing list.